# Electronic pressure "switch"

Tags: switches

I need to gradually switch (ON-OFF or OFF-ON) the output of an 8 bar air compressor by using a uController. I don't want to turn on/off the compressor itself.

Can You help me to identify such a "switch"?

Comment: Did you search on line for pressure switch or a pressure sensor.  (We use some honeywell pressure sensors.)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold: A pressure switch merely creates a binary ON-OFF signal or contact closure at some pressure point with, perhaps, some hysteresis about that point.  A pressure sensor generally provides a parameter (voltage, resistance, etc.) which varies as some function of the pressure applied to its input.  Neither will satisfy the OP's need for the valve-like device he describes.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you're looking for is an [electronic pressure regulator](http://www.parker.com/portal/site/PARKER/menuitem.7100150cebe5bbc2d6806710237ad1ca/?vgnextoid=f5c9b5bbec622110VgnVCM10000032a71dacRCRD&vgnextfmt=EN&vgnextcatid=3029502&vgnextcat=ELECTRONIC%20PRESSURE%20REGULATORS) where you control the slope of the control voltage to vary the output pressure from zero to max or from max to zero in the time you want.